# Find NULL pointer dereferences for function parameters using clang static analyzer

Tags: c, pointers, null, clang, analyzer

I want to automatically find bugs where a potential NULL pointer is dereferenced. In particular, I want to check that all function in my project correctly handle `NULL` as value for pointers.

Here is a quick example:

```
void foo(int *x) {
    *x = 5;
}
```

For this function I want to get a warning because the function `foo` dereferences a `NULL` pointer if `x` is `NULL`.

I tried to use [Clang Static Analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) but the analyzer does not report a problem.

Is there a way to automatically find problems like this?

Comment: This could help - [https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#null_checking](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html#null_checking).

Comment: What is the correct way to handle NULL?

Comment: In the case of the function `foo` a check like `if(x == NULL) return;` would be a correct way to handle `NULL`. My goal is to be sure that there is no execution path that dereferences a `NULL` pointer. I guess it is hard to ensure this in _every_ case, but it should be pretty simple for a static analyzer to find such issues in _most_ cases.

Comment: Only recently I learned about `void foo(int x[static 1]) { ... }` to check against `NULL`. Does this help you? Depending on your needs you can make the size even larger.

Comment: Unfortunately, clang's warnings for null checks appear to be limited to Objective C[++].